# query criteria to output records from the last 90 minutes

Tags: ms-access

I have a time/date field in my select query and I would like to set the criteria to only output records from the last 90 minutes. please give me the proper SQL to copy/paste 
thanks very much, Nathaniel

```
SELECT SYSADM_CUSTOMER_ORDER.PRINTED_DATE
FROM SYSADM_CUSTOMER_ORDER;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MS Access you are looking for something like

```
SELECT SYSADM_CUSTOMER_ORDER.PRINTED_DATE
FROM SYSADM_CUSTOMER_ORDER
WHERE (((SYSADM_CUSTOMER_ORDER.PRINTED_DATE) Between DateAdd("n",-90,Now()) And Now()));
```

Have a look at [Now Function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/now-function-HA001228887.aspx) and [DateAdd Function](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/dateadd.php)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using MS Access with and MS Access backend. Because this is VBA code it will not work in the query screen.

```
Dim dteBeginTime as Date
dteBeginTime = DateAdd("n", -90, Now())
SELECT SYSADM_CUSTOMER_ORDER.PRINTED_DATE
FROM SYSADM_CUSTOMER_ORDER
WHERE PRINTED_DATE > #" & dteBeginTime & "#;"
```

Comment: I dont know how to apply VBA code. I barely know Access.  is there a functon that i can simply paste into design view critera field?  for examle, when I want to view records from the past 2 days, I use ">=date()-2". please advise. thanks

Comment: astander's answer may work better for you since the VBA is embedded in the SQL statement. I think it does what you are asking for.

Comment: There is no VBA embedded in @astander's SQL. It's just functions that are usable within Jet/ACE SQL that have counterparts in VBA -- they actually aren't the same functions as the VBA versions (e.g., IIf() behaves differently in SQL than in VBA).